# Use mysql data output in different ways in nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mapping, ejs

I have an output of a number of bookings which I have to use in a couple of ways.

I will use it to display a list of current bookings and also a list of past bookings, based on a "dateto" field in a timestamp format

Instead of making multiple queries ( WHERE dateto < currentdate, WHERE dateto > currentdate, etc. ) I just want to use the data I already have, but I am a bit unsure how to approach this.

I have this code.

```
let list = (req, res, next) => {

    fetchAll(req.params.hid).then((bookings) => {

        if (bookings.length > 0) {

            (async () => {

                res.render('profile/bookings/bookings.ejs', {
                    bookings: bookings,
                    moment: moment,
                    totalDays: await countBookingDays(bookings)
                })

            })()

        } else {
            res.send('No result')
        }

    }).catch((error) => {
        res.status(500).send(error)
    })

}
```

`countBookingDays()` is just a function that sums all booking days in a year-to-date - not important for this particular issue.

I want to take `bookings` and somehow mapping it to make a new array (pastBookings) with dateto < currentdate

So in my EJS file i can use it with something like this

```
res.render('profile/bookings/bookings.ejs', {
    currentBookings: bookingsMappedToCurrent,
    pastBookings: bookingsMappedToPast
    moment: moment,
    totalDays: await countBookingDays(bookings)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man! It's easy to overcomplicate things

```
let currentBookings = bookings.filter(booking => booking.b_dateto > timeNow)
let pastBookings = bookings.filter(booking => booking.b_dateto < timeNow)
```

Works perfectly fine!